# Image size different after second click on it

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have following minimal working example, taken from my current project:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true

    width: Screen.width/2
    height: Screen.height/2

    property real ueMinOpacity: 0.00
    property real ueMaxOpacity: 1.00

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 8

        border.color: "#4682b4"
        radius: 16

        clip: true

        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#ffffff"
            }   // GradientStop

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#303030"
            }   // GradientStop
        }   // Gradient

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            antialiasing: true

            border.color: "#4682b4"
            border.width: 1

            radius: 16
            clip: true

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop {
                    position: 0
                    color: "#ffffff"
                }   // GradientStop

                GradientStop {
                    position: 1
                    color: "#000000"
                }   // GradientStop
            }   // Gradient

            RowLayout {
                spacing: 8
                anchors.fill: parent

                TextField {
                    id: ueProductSearchTextField

                    antialiasing: true

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter
                    Layout.margins: 8

                    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter product info")
                }   // TextField

                Rectangle {
                    id: ueImageWrapper

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter
                    Layout.margins: 8

                    antialiasing: true

                    border.color: "#4682b4"
                    border.width: 1

                    radius: 16
                    clip: true
                    visible: ueProductSearchTextField.length > 0

                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop {
                            position: 0
                            color: "#636363"
                        }   // GradientStop

                        GradientStop {
                            position: 1
                            color: "#303030"
                        }   // GradientStop
                    }   // Gradient

                    Image {
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        source: "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9iR/gEX/9iRgEXXxT.png"

                        antialiasing: true

                        clip: true

                        smooth: true

                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

                        horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

                        sourceSize.width: 96
                        sourceSize.height: 96
                    }   // Image

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        enabled: ueImageWrapper.visible

                        onClicked: {
                            ueProductSearchTextField.text="";
                        }   // onClicked
                    }   // MouseArea


                    onWidthChanged: {
                        print("ueImageWrapper.width:"+ueImageWrapper.width);
                    }   // onWidthChanged

                    onHeightChanged: {
                        print("ueImageWrapper.height:"+ueImageWrapper.height);
                    }   // onHeightChanged
                }   // Rectangle
            }   // RowLayout
        }   // Rectangle
    }   // Rectangle
}   // Window
```

Now, the purpose of this `Item`/`Rectangle` is to filter database records according to `TextField`'s entered value, which works perfectly. However, once `TextField`'s text is not empty anymore (when user enters some string), on the right side of `Layout` `Image` for clearing text is shown via `OpacityAnimator`. Once the app is launched, I get following screenshot - **clear text icon is hidden since there is not text in `TextField`**:
[image: App Start Screenshot]
Then, I enter some text into `TextField` and **clear text** icon pops up:
[image: Tesxt entered Screenshot]
Then, for instance, I clear text by clicking on **clear text** icon and it (icon) is hidden again, which is ok:
[image: Text cleared Screenshot]
And finally, I reenter text into `TextField`, **clear text** icon is visible again, but it has different size:
[image]
Why? I did not change the code. It must be some problem with `Layout`s, but I simply do not see it! Here is also a debug output from `onWidthChanged` and `onHeightChanged` handlers:

> qml: ueImageWrapper.width:37.56521739130435
>       qml: ueImageWrapper.height:480
>       qml: ueImageWrapper.width:132.92307692307693
>       qml: ueImageWrapper.width:133.83783783783784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BaCaRoZzo's suggestion works, but I'm also a bit unsure about why it behaves the way it does. If you take a simpler example:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 800

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Ctrl+Q"
        onActivated: Qt.quit()
    }

    Item {
        id: boundary
        width: 400
        height: 400
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "steelblue"
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rect
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "salmon"
                visible: false
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: boundary
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "black"
    }

    Button {
        text: "Toggle visibility"
        onClicked: rect.visible = !rect.visible
    }
}
```

The second rectangle starts off being invisible, and is then shown/hidden by clicking the button. However, when it starts off as invisible, it never gets a size once shown. On the other hand, if it starts off visible, then it gets half the width of the layout.

If you read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) carefully, it doesn't say that it's necessary to set a `preferredWidth`/`preferredHeight` if you just want to make an item fill the available space. For that reason, it seems like a bug in how layouts handle initial visibility of their items. I'd suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had no time to test it today. :) It smells like a bug to me too! However, setting a `preferredWidth`/`preferredHeight` generally does make sense. At least if you don't want to end up with perfectly split space like in this case. Hope someone can file a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, it does make sense, especially if it's not just an invisible "spacer" item.