# QML recalculate Layout when visibility of children change

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qtquick2

I'm using a `RowLayout` with 2 children in it. If I hide one of them, I want the other child to fill up the complete area. And when unhide it, the area should be evenly divided.

Problem I'm having is when 1 child is hidden at startup, and visibility changes at runtime. The area stays filled with only 1 child (and small bar is shown for spacing). While I expected that both childs would be visible.

Example:

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "red"

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:
            {
                rect2.visible = !rect2.visible
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "blue"
        visible: false
    }
}
```

If I remove the `visible: false` from `rect2`, it works expected. Only I want rect2 to be hidden at startup.

Putting `rect2.visible = false` in `Component.onCompleted` only adds extra code which imho should not be needed.

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: I think you are hitting a common "bug" here. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34854337/2538363) and the related answer.

Comment: The answer there is only a small code example to show the issue. Actual solution is filing a bug report and hope it will be fixed? Any other ways to do this?

Comment: Using `preferredWidth: parent.width / 2` should be the solution right now.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo: for this indeed, defeating the purpose of using the Layout itself. In my project, I have 8+ items, which indepently should be visible or not. Simply dividing by 8 won't do it. I would then count the amount of visible ones and use that.

Comment: I should have been clearer, sorry. The point is `fillwidth` rules over other rules. The bug is related to the fact that, for some reasons, the lack of a `preferredWidth` (or does it suffice `minimumWidth` for instance? Didn't test) does lead to the bug. Without further babbling just try out [this 2 mins example](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/M3N0T9Ly). Also, it seems the feature (still seeing it as a bug...) is scheduled [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45781).

Comment: Hmm cool it works, doesn't matter what preferredWidth is, as long it's the same value everywhere.

Comment: My painful experience: NEVER use `RowLayout` , use `Row` instead. Don't know why `Layout` usually cannot adjust size after any of child's size-changing.